# Show that the seminorm $|\cdot|_p$ satisfies the second norm axiom, a question about $(\cdot)^p$ and $(\cdot)^{1/p}$, when $p = \infty$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, normed-spaces, infinity

### The problem:

I have been asked to show that the *seminorm* $|f|_p$ of a measurable function $f : E\to [-\infty,\infty]$,
\begin{equation}
|f|_p = \left(\int_E |f|^p \rm d\mu\right)^{1/p} \in[0,\infty]
\end{equation}
satisfies the second axiom in the definition of the norm:
\begin{equation}
\lVert cx\rVert = \lvert c \rvert \lVert x\rVert,
\end{equation}
for all $c\in\mathbb R$ and $x \in X$, where $X$ is a vector space.

Now, for the proof to be complete, I need to consider both cases, $1 \leq p < \infty$ and $p = \infty$.
The first case is not really and issue,
since for all $p\in [1,\infty)$,
\begin{align}
|cf|_p
&= \left(\int_E |cf|^p \rm d\mu\right)^{1/p}\\
&= \left(\int_E |c|^p |f|^p \rm d\mu\right)^{1/p}\\
&= \left(|c|^p\int_E  |f|^p \rm d\mu\right)^{1/p} && (\text{Homogeneity of integration})\\
&= |c|^{p\frac 1 p}\left(\int_E  |f|^p \rm d\mu\right)^{1/p}\\
&= |c|\left(\int_E  |f|^p \rm d\mu\right)^{1/p}\\
&= |c| |f|_p
\end{align}

What I'm struggling with is the idea of an infinite root, $(\cdot)^{1/p}$, especially since the target of $f$ is $[-\infty,\infty]$.
I could end up with things like $\infty^{1/\infty}$ or $(-\infty)^{1/\infty}$, which I don't know how to deal with.

How should I approach this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $L^{\infty}$ norm is actually defined as
$$ \lVert f \rVert_{\infty} = \inf \{ \lambda \geq  0 : \lvert f(x) \rvert \leq \lambda\ \text{almost everywhere} \}$$
so you don't need to try and make sense of what an $\infty$ root is. Because it's not of the same form, the $p = \infty$ case is usually treated separately in proof that the $p < \infty$ case.

Comment: I'm assuming $0 \leq \lambda < \infty$, here?

Comment: @TheSodesa Sorry, should have been clearer. $\lambda = \infty$ is possible.

Comment: Annoyingly enough, the definition of $|f|_\infty$ was covered in a totally separate place in the lecture slides. There it is given as the essential supremum $|f|_\infty = {\rm ess\,sup}_{x\in E}|f(x)| := \inf\{c\geq 0 : |f(x)| \leq c \text{ for almost every $x\in E$}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The seminorm $|\cdot|_p$ as $p\to\infty$ is the [supremum norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm) $|\cdot|_\infty$ defined by,

$$|f|_\infty=\sup\{|f(x)|\colon x\in E\}$$

When $f$ is continuous, we have,

$$\lim_{p\to\infty}|f|_p=|f|_\infty$$

To see this, note that,

$$|f|_p:= \left(\int_E |f|^p \rm d\mu\right)^{1/p}=(|f(c)|^p\mu(E))^{1/p}=|f(c)|\left(\mu(E)\right)^{1/p}\to |f(c)|\leq\sup_{c\in E}|f(x)|=:|f|_\infty$$

as $p\to\infty$ for some $c\in E$ by the MVT for integrals.